# Firewall use-case on a server with no open ports?

Tags: security, firewall

I know a firewall is a must on any machine connected to the Internet, no matter what.

I was wondering though what would be a firewall use-case on a server with absolutely no open ports. For example, a machine operated from a local console, possibly only used to fetch data, but never to serve to the outside.

Would the firewall's only purpose just to log attacks attempts, and possibly blocking them via Fail2Ban, or similar service?

In other words, if the firewall, let's say `pf`, would specify something like,

```
block in all
pass out all keep state
```

What would be the specific benefit of `block in all`, since all ports are off by default, including `ssh`, etc?

Answer (score 4):

> Would the firewall's only purpose just to log attacks attempts, and possibly blocking them via Fail2Ban, or similar service?

Defense in depth. Blocking everything incoming means that a single misconfiguration won't expose anything to the network. Errors are less likely to lead to security problems when the misconfigured service can't receive external traffic.

Comment: Also reducing the attack surface a threat actor has.Start blocking all traffic by default and only allow specific traffic to identified services. This approach provides quality control over the traffic and decreases the possibility of a breach. This behavior can also be achieved by configuring the last rule in an access control list to deny all traffic. Modifications can be done explicitly or implicitly, depending on the platform.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a public IP address then the machine is vulnerable to any mistakes. Install a new service that has ports open by default and you are immediately vulnerable. Accidentally open a port on an existing service and you have a problem. Have a port on a service that you don't even know exists on your machine (e.g. Windows has tonnes of stuff that runs by default) and you have a problem.

It also adds almost no time/overhead to install and gets muscle memory developed that all public facing servers have a firewall.

Yes, it could be used for logging access attempts but if you are never going to look at them, then this isn't really an advantage.

If you are only using a machine for fetching, you should put it behind a NAT router so nothing external can physically get to it.